# Compare 2 subsets of data from table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I'm not sure if this is possible - I'm having real trouble getting my head around it.

This is for a product schedule, showing how much we are expecting to deliver on a given date. Data is imported into this schedule weekly which creates a new entry.

For example, if the schedule for the day currently totals 10, and you import 15, a new row is inserted with Qty 5, bringing the sum to 15.

The data I have is like so:

```
Product | Delivery Required Date | Qty 
Prod1   |       1/1/13           | 10
Prod1   |       1/1/13           | -10
Prod1   |       1/1/13           | 10
Prod1   |       1/1/13           | -10
Prod1   |       1/1/13           | 25
```

I want to design a query which shows the variance between the previous schedule, and the current schedule.

For example, the query will sum all of the rows "Qty", excluding the last entry - and compare it to the last entry. In the data above, the variance is 25 (Existing total was 0, latest entry is 25, 0+25 =25).

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a primary key on that table?  (Each record having a unique ID number)?  It would make the query a LOT easier.

Comment: I do yes, I've simplified the data a lot in this example sorry. "Entry No" is the PK.

I had a thought, perhaps the calculation could be:

The sum of all rows, minus 2 * the last row's Qty? If it makes it any easier

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there'a better answer using Common Table Expressions, but a quick & ugly solution might be

```
select sum(case when EntryNo <> MAX(EntryNo) then Qty else 0 end) as 'sumLessLast'
from MyTable
```

If `MyTable` has a million rows in it you'll want a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

SqlServer 2005 and 2008:

```
;with r1 as (
    select DeliveryReqDate, sum(Qty) as TotalQty
    from TableName
    group by DeliveryReqDate)
, r2 as (
    select DeliveryReqDate, Qty
        , row_number() over (partition by DeliveryReqDate order by EntryNo desc) rn
    from TableName)
select r1.DeliveryReqDate, r1.TotalQty, r2.Qty as LastQty
    , r1.TotalQty - r2.Qty as TotalButLastQty
from r1
    join r2 on r2.DeliveryReqDate = r1.DeliveryReqDate and r2.rn = 1
```

SqlServer 2012

```
;with r1 as (
    select DeliveryReqDate, Qty
        , sum(Qty) over (partition by DeliveryReqDate) as TotalQty
        , row_number() over (partition by DeliveryReqDate order by EntryNo desc) rn
from TableName)
select DeliveryReqDate, TotalQty, Qty as LastQty
    , TotalQty - Qty as TotalButLastQty
from r1
where rn = 1
```

I'm not sure that I completely understand logic regarding the accounting of product and date, but I hope you can adapt above queries to your needs.